# How to set value of a editable combo box in an InternetExplorer window using VBScript?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, combobox, automation

can anyone please tell me how to set the value of a editable combobox in an IE window using vbscript?

I have set the IE window that i want to use, as an object.

If it was a text box, i have used

```
ie.document.all("textboxname").value = "textboxvalue"
```

For radiobutton, i have used

```
ie.document.all("radiobuttonname")(2).click            --- where '2' is index of array (3rd value in array is selected)
```

For noneditable combobox, i have used

```
ie.document.all("comboboxname").selectedindex = 2    --- where '2' is index of array
```

All the above codes work fine, but I am not able to set value for the editable comboboxes in that IE window.

For editable combobox, i tried

```
ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname").selectedindex = 2
```

or

```
ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname").selectedindex.text = "text of any options in the combobox"
```

or

```
ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname").selectedindex(2).click
```

or

```
ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname").options.selected = 2
```

But everything leads to this error - "Object doesn't support this property or method: "

Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks in advance

Please note I am using only VBscript and no other tools like Visual Studio or QTP.

As per Panayot Karabakalov asked, I have added an example of the code for one such editable combo box below :

```
<td class="small">        
<span id="Curr Car Name" style = "display:none;"  class = "small">          
Curr Car Name 
<font  class="asteriskRed" style="font-size:11px" style="display:none;">*</font><br>
<input type="hidden" name='curr_car_name' id='curr_car_name' value='' style='width:180px;height=20px;' >

<script>
getTypeAhead(true,true,'curr_car_name',180,20,'null','AutoCompleteHighlight',  'AutoCompleteBackground','divclass','null',5,20,'curr_car_name_datasrc','','null',0,'setHHChangeIndicator();priorValidations();deleteRowFromAccordion(this);',310,100,'null','');
searchandFill('curr_car_name','',curr_car_name_datasrc);</script>
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="currentcarriernameHdd" id="currentcarriernameHdd" value="null"/>
</td
```

I saved the webpage(created in Java) as html file and viewed its source code. From there, I have copied and pasted the code for the combobox above. I am not sure if it will be helpful, as I dont have much knowledge of Java.

-- Deepak.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp#gsc.tab=0. Can you try with `selectedIndex` instead of `selectedindex`? The case matters.

Comment: @ shahkalpesh - I tried with "selectedIndex" as you said, but error is the same. I do not think the Capital letter matters, as VBscript is not case sensitive.

Comment: Can you post a code for your editable combobox to see how it looks like

Comment: Panayot, I am not sure if the code that I have posted is what you asked for. I am trying to automate a website using VBscript, for testing purpose. This website is created using Java. I dont have much knowledge about Java, so it has been very difficult for me. To view the code for combo boxes, text boxes, radio buttons or so, I save the web page as a html file and view the source code. what i posted above is from that source code. Is it enough for you? Please let me know if you needed some other code. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, first to note, do not post a code in comments, that make it unreadable, but edit your question instead. As for the code itself, I not see `select` tag inside. Maybe your combobox is generated dynamical via script? Anyway, that code not helps me to see your combobox.

Comment: @Panayot - I also went through the entire code for select tags, but none of the editable combo boxes seem to have them. Does that mean it is dynamically generated? If so, is there no way to set the values through vbscript? And i have edited the question and  added the code there, instead of pasting in comments.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll post what I have in mind.

Looking to the error description (*Object doesn't support this property or method*), 
seems to me that your call-by-name...

```
ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname")
```

...return different object, i.e. not the element you expected. And as you have not 
access to the plain HTML source code, that complicate debuging.

I suspect a naming conflict. What you can do is to see what returns your call-by-name.

```
MsgBox TypeName(ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname").Type)
```

But if there some naming conflict, I don't know how you can debug it without 
the actual corresponding HTML code block.

Comment: As you said, I tried

MsgBox TypeName(ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname"))
It returns the value "HTMLInputElement" . What should I understand from that? Is it detecting it as a textbox and not as a combo box?

Comment: @DeepakNarayan - `HTMLInputElement` can be any `type` (button, checkbox, radio, submit, etc.). All this is shot-in-the-dark debuging. Try to change `Size` property. That at least will show which element is affected.

Answer (score 0):

@ Panayot - Got the answer to my question!!

As you said, I tried with

```
MsgBox TypeName(ie.document.all("editablecomboboxname").Type)
```

It returned "String". So I went to a Java colleague of mine and asked him why the combobox is not getting updated even though inputtype is string. After a lot of discussion, he gave me two fields to update for the combobox - a label field to be updated with the string that I wanted in the combobox and another field to be updated with the value corresponding to the string I selected. This is what I used :

```
ie.document.all("curr_car_name").value = 8001

ie.document.all("_lblcurr_car_name").value = "NO PRIOR CARRIER"
```

The "curr_car_name" is the editable combobox name, and the "_lblcurr_car_name" is the label for the editable combobox. "NO PRIOR CARRIER" is the text that I wanted the combobox to have, and 8001 is its corresponding value. I got the value 8001 from the javascript that the webpage contained.
This works. :)
Thank you Panayot for all the help.